# Creating category to show hours as a KPI

Tags: tableau-api

Need help with calculation in Tableau. I have field as priority High, Medium and Low.
For High and medium i have the TAT as 2 hours and for low it is 4 hours.
I need to add a calculation which for each ticket based on their priority level shows respective priority hours as either 2 or 4 hours.
I have added a calculation :

```
if [Priority]= "High" then "2 Hours" 
ELSEIF [Priority]= "Medium" then "2 Hours" 
ELSE "4 Hours"
END
```

however this is a string whereas i need it in hour format so that i can add a flag whether ticket missed or met the SLA.
This i would do basis another column which is time taken to acknowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let’s consider `Start Time = 07/06/2017 5:30:00 AM` and `End Time = 07/06/2017 8:40:00 AM`

---

Create a calculated field (`time_diff_seconds`) to calculate time difference between start & end time

```
(DATEDIFF('hour’,[Start Time],[End Time]) * 3600) + (DATEDIFF(‘minute’,[Start Time],[End Time]) * 60) + DATEDIFF(’second’,[Start Time],[End Time])
```

Now coming back to your calculated field (`SLA_seconds`) definition, I would modify it to look something like:

```
IF [Priority]= "High" then 2*3600 
ELSEIF [Priority]= "Medium" then 2*3600
ELSE 4*3600
END
```

Then finally create your flag as another calculated field i.e. `SLA_met`

```
IF time_diff_seconds <= SLA_seconds THEN “Y”
ELSE “N”
END
```

---

*Hope this helps! Pls don't forget to mention if it solves your problem :)*

Comment: massive just one question. I have been trying to figure why we add 3600 this is for seconds and then minutes is multiplied by 60. What is the rational

Comment: Shouldn't we compare apple with apple not oranges? So I changed time difference to 'second' and then compared it with defined SLA time in 'second'. 

You could have done it using 'hour' comparison as well and the answer would have been same but with this solution you can also calculate - "by how much 'exact' time you missed the SLA?" :))